# How to get nested populated property in mongodb in nestjs/mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

The Json below is returned from this method

```
const ByTheId = await this.service.GetById(ID);
```

I want to access the Owner properties, I tried to get

```
ByTheId.Owner._id
```

But that didnt work

```
{
  "_id": "5eb905426564556758754",
  "PhysicalId": "023546757986",
  "SerialNumber": "serial-65867546712345587",
  "Owner": {
    "_id": "5ecbxderw9gf6dct4833a54",
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Doe",
    "email": "john@doe.com",
    "phonenumber": "887-8789-878",
    "address": "007 John Street",
    "lga": "Shira",
    "state": "State"
  }
}
```

schema

```
   Owner: {
        type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'User'
    },
```

method

```
 async GetById(Id: any): Promise<DTO> {
        return await this.Model.findById(Id).populate('Owner', {
            _id: 1,
            firstname: 1,
            lastname: 1,
            email: 1,
            phonenumber: 1,
            address: 1,
            state: 1,
            lga: 1,
        });
    }
```

Those are the properties I want it to return from owner object
How can I access the id property of the owner?

Comment: what is your schema? Have you tried debugging `ByTheId`?

Comment: Have added schema to the code

Comment: You’d have to “populate” for ref properties

Comment: Yes I did that, please check updated code